# Recursive keycloak broker throwing a cookie exception

Tags: cookies, keycloak

I am trying to setup following transitive architecture:

- (A) Keycloak as a user federation on AD
- (B) Keycloak as a broker for Keycloak (A)
- (C) Keycloak as a broker for Keycloak (B) connected to some services provider

```
     ----       -----       -----       -----
    | AD | <-- | (A) | <-- | (B) | <-- | (C) |
     ----       -----       -----       -----
```

What I have: I am getting a missing cookie exception when I try to connect to Keycloak (C).

The connection is successful to Keycloak (A) and Keycloak (B).

[image: missing cookie when forwarded to Keycloak (C)]

What I want: a successful connection to Keycloak (C).

Do you know if this is achievable? If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: welcome, did you done research, have you created a ticket on the vendor?

Comment: Thanks for your question, yes I dug the entire Internet without finding the same situation. I did not opened a ticket yet as I wanted to have some insights before doing so

Comment: please show us examples, and why they cant help you in your situation. ;)
did you opened a ticket on the vendor of the software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: each keycloak must be deployed on distinct hosts otherwise the token is being removed when forwarded back from IDP authentication

As a conclusion, it is doable to chain multiple keycloaks as brokers

Thanks all